# Intuitive interpretation of this congruence theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Proposition 3.1. Let $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}, m_1,m_2\in\mathbb Z^+$ and $\gcd(m_1,m_2)=1$. Then
$$\begin{cases} a &\equiv b \pmod{m_1} \\ a &\equiv b \pmod{m_2}\\ \end{cases} \implies a\equiv b \pmod{m_1m_2}$$.

---

Is there an intuitive way to think about this result? I get the proof, but am not seeing how this is "obviously true". That is, why is it that when I can write some conrguence $a\equiv b$ in two different mods, they are also the same thing in the product of their mods.

Comment: Hint: $a-b$ is a *common multiple* of $m_1$ and $m_2$, so think in terms of LCM.

Answer (score 0):

For some integers $\ell$ and $k$, by definition of congruence we have that
$$\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}\begin{array}{l}a = b + {m_1}k\\a = b + {m_2}\ell \end{array}\end{array}\quad  \Rightarrow \quad {m_1}k = {m_2}\ell $$
Both sides of the equation ${m_1}k = {m_2}\ell $ ought to have the same factors. Since $m_{1}$ and $m_{2}$ share no common factors, all of the factors of $m_{2}$ are contained in $k$. In other words, $k = u \cdot {m_2}$ for some integer $u$. Substituting this into the first congruence, $$a = b + u \cdot {m_1}{m_2}\quad  \Rightarrow \quad a \equiv b\bmod {m_1}{m_2}$$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).